# How can I secure my use of Devise/CanCan/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I have a Controller that's protected by Devise/CanCan with `:authenticate_user!` and `load_and_authorize_resource`. I have to add `:except => [:sort]` to those in order to get my `sort` action working in javascript because the javascript connections to the `sort` action don't include `current_user` or its Role.

I've gotten around the issue by using [gon](https://rubygems.org/gems/gon) to pass the Role of the `current_user` (and if there isn't a `current_user`, then it passes 'anonymous'). I'm not certain whether this is secure on the JavaScript side (maybe the variable can be set/overridden in the browser's console), and I'm certain that my `sort` action isn't secure because I've left it open for direct POST access - I tested this with RESTed by sending the action correct parameters, which resulted in re-sorted data.

So: How do I enable secure access to Rails Controllers that are protected by Devise/CanCan from JavaScript?

Here are the details of my Rails app...

This is the (truncated) Controller, displaying how I'm exempting the `sort` action from Devise/CanCan & setting the `gon.current_user_role` variable to the Role of the `current_user`, if available:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:sort]
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:sort]

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    if current_user
      gon.current_user_role = current_user.role
    else
      gon.current_user_role = "anonymous"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def sort
    params[:thing].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Thing.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end

end
```

In my view, I've got an unordered list of items that should be sortable *only* by users with the 'admin' Role:

```
<ul class="things" data-update-url="<%= sort_things_url %>">
  <% @things.each do |t| %>
    <%= content_tag_for(:li, t) do %>
      <%= image_tag t.image %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here's the javascript in application.js file, where I'm only making the list sortable if the `gon.current_user_role` variable is 'admin':

```
$(function() {
  if (gon.current_user_role == "admin")
  {
    $( ".things" ).sortable({
      update: function() {
        return $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
      }
    });
    $( ".things" ).disableSelection();
  }
});
```

Finally, my routes.rb file opens up the `sort` action to POST calls:

```
  resources :things do
    collection { post :sort }
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken about the JavaScript connections to the sort action not including `current_user` or its Role. The reason I was mistaken was because I'm using [Pow](http://pow.cx/), so I've been accessing my Rails app at http://railsapp.dev ... but my JavaScript requests are marked as being from 127.0.0.1 ... So they're treated as XSS requests.

When I fired up the standard Rails server with `rails s`, or when I made these attempts on the staging server, JavaScript knew about the `current_user`.

My Controller ended up like this:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    if current_user
      gon.current_user_role = current_user.role
    else
      gon.current_user_role = "anonymous"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def sort
    params[:thing].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Thing.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end

end
```

My View and JavaScript stayed the same.

This setup disallows arbitrary POST calls to the `sort` action, and also keeps the items from being rearranged by people without the 'admin' Role. If someone *does* figure out how to manipulate the `gon.current_user_role` JavaScript variable, they will be able to visibly rearrange the items on the page but that rearrangement will not be stored in the database because the `sort` action will disallow the request (and their changes will be reverted on the next page load).

This setup does not resolve my issues with Pow, but I can live with that.